# Set parameters in the query based on the condition

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I need to write a query with multiple `where` condition and `OR` condition. This `OR` condition is only when if `$location` array is not empty. So parameters are needed only when this array is not empty.

I am not sure how to write this parameter condition in this condition.

This is the query I am working on.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("e")
            ->select(
                 "e.vehicleId",
                 "e.schemaId",
                 "e.location",
            )
            ->andWhere("e.vehicleId = :vehicleId")
            ->andWhere("e.optionId = :optionId")
            ->andWhere("e.schemaId = :schemaId");
if (count($position) > 0) {
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->andX("e.location = :location"),
                $qb->expr()->andX("e.location = :loc")
            ));
}

$qb->setParameters(array(
            "vehicleId" => $vehicleId,
            "schemaId" => $schemaId,
            "location" => $position["location"],
            "loc" => $position["loc"],
        ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QueryBuilder` has two methods to set the query parameters.

The one you are using (`setParameters(array $parameters)`, and the simpler `setParameter($parameterName, $parameterValue)`.

Use the latter instead of the one you are using, and you can set the parameter where you need it:

```
if (count($position) > 0) {
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->andX("e.location = :location"),
                $qb->expr()->andX("e.location = :loc")
            ))
        ->setParameter('location', $position["location"])
        ->setParameter('loc', $position["loc"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create parameteR array that holds conditional parameters.

```
if (count($position) > 0) {
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->andX("e.location = :location"),
        $qb->expr()->andX("e.location = :loc")
    ));

     $parameter["location"] = $position["location"];
     $parameter["loc"] = $position["loc"];
}
```

And then pass and merge this parameter array into setParameters method.

```
$qb->setParameters(array_merge(
        array(
            "vehicleId" => $vehicleId,
            "schemaId" => $schemaId,
        ),
        $parameters
));
```